# How to not capture multiple letters

Tags: regex

```
/**
 * SOMETHING BLABLABLA
 * Date: 3/16/14
 * Time: 8:29 PM
 */
```

I want to match anything from /** to */

I can match /** to the first * with this:

```
/\*\*([^\*]*)\*
```

But I don't know how to unmatch both last two letters.

Comment: javascript I think, I don't know it is something used in phpstorm / textmate / sublime when you use Find regex feature

Comment: What do you mean by _unmatch_?

Comment: This doesn't match any letters in your example?  Do you mean characters?  Can you show an example of what you want?

Comment: I wonder if perhaps you want a positive lookahead, e.g. `(?=\*\/)`. I suspect not, though, given that you _are_ already capturing the first `/*`

Comment: @jaycode Different "flavors" of regex have different syntaxes and different features in some areas. Are you using this in PHP, or in TextMate, or in Sublime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, which requires dot-matches-all:

```
/\*\*.*?\*/
```

Alternatively, this captures all post-asterisk text on each line...sort of:

```
/\*\*(?:\s+\* ([^\r\n]+))+\s+\*/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GVDEOXaRb86WNMRc)

Actually it only captures the last line, but it does seem closer.

Comment: That'll match the whole comment, which is what at first what I thought he wanted, but I don't think that's it...

Comment: almost the same thing I thought of, and I think it matches what the asker wanted, `/(\/\*\*.*?\*\/)/m`

Comment: I updated to something a little closer, I think, but I'm not clear on what is wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
/(?:^\s*\/\*\*)(.*)(?:^\s*\*\/)/ms
```

[See it work](http://regex101.com/r/eG7fB2)

Or Debuggex version:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iITWf6kc1Zr-2jDJ)

By 'unmatch' I think you mean have a group that is not included in the match group. You use a non capturing group that starts with `(?:regex)` to do that.

The full explanation is:

```
/(?:^\s*\/\*\*)(.*)(?:\s*\*\/)/ms
(?:^\s*\/\*\*) Non-capturing group
    ^ assert position at start of a line
    \s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
    giving back as needed [greedy]
    \/ matches the character / literally
    \* matches the character * literally
    \* matches the character * literally
1st Capturing group (.*)
    .* matches any character
    Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
    giving back as needed [greedy]
(?:\s*\*\/) Non-capturing group
    \s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \* matches the character * literally
    \/ matches the character / literally
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
```

If you want to match:

```
/**
 * SOMETHING BLABLABLA
 * Date: 3/16/14
 * Time: 8:29 PM*/
                ^ comment terminator
```

Just remove the anchor in the final non capturing group to be `(?:\s*\*\/)`

---

For Sublime, you need the flags `ms` to be set. Use:

```
(?ms)(?:^\s*\/\*\*)(.*)(?:^\s*\*\/)
^^^^ This part sets the flags for Boost regex engine...
```

Comment: This would also capture non JavaDoc blocks. It needs a second asterisk in the open marker: `(?:^\s*\/\*\*)(.*)(?:^\s*\*\/)`

Comment: Hi, it does not work when I use sublime text editor to find. Any idea why?